# Convert 2D float array to 2D int array in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

How do I convert a float NumPy array into an int NumPy array?

Answer (score 477, accepted):

Use the [`astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1.0, 2.3], [1.3, 2.9]])
>>> x
array([[ 1. ,  2.3],
       [ 1.3,  2.9]])
>>> x.astype(int)
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Just make sure you don't have `np.inf`or `np.nan` in your array, since they have surprising results.  For example, `np.array([np.inf]).astype(int)` outputs `array([-9223372036854775808])`.

Comment: On my machine, `np.array([np.inf]).astype(int)`, `np.array([-np.inf]).astype(int)`, and `np.array([np.nan]).astype(int)` all return the same thing. Why?

Comment: @BallpointBen: `nan` and `inf` are floating-point values and can't be meaningfully converted to int.  As the comment before yours notes, there will be surprising behavior, and I don't think the precise behavior is well-defined.  If you want to map `nan` and `inf` to certain values, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Note that x.astype(int)[0][0] is not of type `int`. It's `numpy.int32`.

Comment: Note that although this does convert the array to ints, @fhtuft's answer that may result in less surprises

Answer (score 78):

Some numpy functions for how to control the rounding: [rint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rint.html#numpy.rint), [floor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html#numpy.floor),[trunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trunc.html#numpy.trunc), [ceil](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html). depending how  u wish to round the floats, up, down, or to the nearest int.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1.0,2.3],[1.3,2.9]])
>>> x
array([[ 1. ,  2.3],
       [ 1.3,  2.9]])
>>> y = np.trunc(x)
>>> y
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
>>> z = np.ceil(x)
>>> z
array([[ 1.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3.]])
>>> t = np.floor(x)
>>> t
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
>>> a = np.rint(x)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

To make one of this in to int, or one of the  other types in numpy, [astype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) (as answered by BrenBern):

```
a.astype(int)
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3]])

>>> y.astype(int)
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. `astype` is often too generic, and I think it probably is more useful when doing intx - inty conversions. When I want to do float - int conversion being able to choose the kind of rounding is a nice feature.

Comment: So the simplest way to safely convert almost-ints like `7.99999` to ints like `8`, is `np.rint(arr).astype(int)`?

Comment: any way in numpy to make it uint8?

Comment: @Ryan `astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: Can you also comment on the runtime of these methods ?

Answer (score 19):

you can use `np.int_`:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1.0, 2.3], [1.3, 2.9]])
>>> x
array([[ 1. ,  2.3],
       [ 1.3,  2.9]])
>>> np.int_(x)
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 18):

If you're not sure your input is going to be a Numpy array, you can use `asarray` with `dtype=int` instead of `astype`:

```
>>> np.asarray([1,2,3,4], dtype=int)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If the input array already has the correct dtype, `asarray` avoids the array copy while `astype` does not (unless you specify `copy=False`):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a is np.asarray(a)  # no copy :)
True
>>> a is a.astype(int)  # copy :(
False
>>> a is a.astype(int, copy=False)  # no copy :)
True
```