# How can I convert a numpy array of float type into a numpy array of int type?

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I have the following source code:

```
npW_x = np.array(my_np_array)
npW_round_111 = np.around(npW_x, decimals=0)
sum_x_111 = np.sum(npW_round_111, axis=1)

np.savetxt("file1.txt", sum_x_111)
```

**File output**

```
3.200000000000000000e+01
5.500000000000000000e+01
3.300000000000000000e+01
4.900000000000000000e+01
5.200000000000000000e+01
5.500000000000000000e+01
3.800000000000000000e+01
5.200000000000000000e+01
5.100000000000000000e+01
3.100000000000000000e+01
3.100000000000000000e+01
3.200000000000000000e+01
5.100000000000000000e+01
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
3
6
3
5
5
6
4
5
5
3
3
3
5
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: You can supply the `dtype` of your choice - `np.sum(npW_round_111, axis=1,dtype=np.int64)`

Comment: I think you can use the astype(int) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873824/how-to-convert-2d-float-numpy-array-to-2d-int-numpy-array

Comment: Note, you're not going to get that "expected" output. `3.200000000000000000e+01` is 32.0, not 3.0. The `e+01` means "times 10 to the 1st power".

Comment: Unduping because this isn't just a dtype issue. There *is* a dtype issue, but it's not the only issue - `numpy.savetxt` defaults to `fmt='%.18e'` even if you pass it an array of integer dtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [385]: npW_x = np.random.rand(4,5)*10
     ...: npW_round_111 = np.around(npW_x, decimals=0)
     ...: sum_x_111 = np.sum(npW_round_111, axis=1)
     ...: 
In [386]: sum_x_111
Out[386]: array([38., 25., 24., 30.])
```

save with default `fmt` (Read and reread the `np.savetxt` docs!)

```
In [387]: np.savetxt('test',sum_x_111)
In [388]: cat test
3.800000000000000000e+01
2.500000000000000000e+01
2.400000000000000000e+01
3.000000000000000000e+01
```

save with int format:

```
In [389]: np.savetxt('test',sum_x_111, fmt='%10d')
In [390]: cat test
        38
        25
        24
        30
```

conversion in memory to int:

```
In [391]: In [391]: sum_x_111.astype(int)
Out[391]: array([38, 25, 24, 30])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `astype()` function for this

I'm considering `npW_x` to be the array which needs to be converted into int array.

```
npW_x = np.array(my_np_array)
npW_x = npW_x.astype('int32')
```

Now, it should be converted into an integer numpy array.

Edit:

I have added the full code, so that you can try

```
npW_x = np.array(my_np_array)
npW_x = npW_x.astype('int32')
sum_x_111 = np.sum(npW_x, axis=1)
np.savetxt("file1.txt", sum_x_111)
```

Hope it resolved your problem.

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: May i know what error did you get?

Comment: The `file1.txt` contains values with decimal points. E.g. `6.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00`, etc.

Comment: i have added the full code. do tell me if it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr = np.asarray([3.200000000000000000e+01,
5.500000000000000000e+01,
3.300000000000000000e+01,
4.900000000000000000e+01,
5.200000000000000000e+01,
5.500000000000000000e+01,
3.800000000000000000e+01,
5.200000000000000000e+01,
5.100000000000000000e+01,
3.100000000000000000e+01,
3.100000000000000000e+01,
3.200000000000000000e+01,
5.100000000000000000e+01])
```

arr

```py
array([32. , 55. , 33. , 49. , 52. , 55. , 38. , 52. , 51. , 31. , 31. ,
       32. ,  5.1])
```

```py
np.around(np.where(arr//10, arr/10, arr)).astype('int')
```

get

```py
array([3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5])
```

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The `file1.txt` contains values with decimal points. E.g. `6.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00`, etc.